Работа с дочерними окнами в pywinauto
Не могу получить доступ к дочерним окнам. Взял для примера окно консоли в PyCharm. Если оно Docked, то окно не находится среди дочерних элементов:
app.window().print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:
Dialog - 'PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.py'    (L-9, T-9, R1929, B1039)
['Dialog', 'PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.pyDialog', 'PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.py']
child_window(title="PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.py", control_type="Window")
|
| TitleBar - ''    (L0, T-6, R1920, B0)
| ['TitleBar']
|    |
|    | Menu - 'Система'    (L0, T0, R28, B28)
|    | ['Система', 'Menu', 'СистемаMenu', 'Система0', 'Система1']
|    | child_window(title="Система", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
|    |    |
|    |    | MenuItem - 'Система'    (L0, T0, R28, B28)
|    |    | ['Система2', 'MenuItem', 'СистемаMenuItem']
|    |    | child_window(title="Система", control_type="MenuItem")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Свернуть'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
|    | ['Button', 'Свернуть', 'СвернутьButton', 'Button0', 'Button1']
|    | child_window(title="Свернуть", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Восстановить'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
|    | ['Button2', 'Восстановить', 'ВосстановитьButton']
|    | child_window(title="Восстановить", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Закрыть'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
|    | ['Button3', 'ЗакрытьButton', 'Закрыть']
|    | child_window(title="Закрыть", control_type="Button")
Если открепить окно, то находится элемент Pane:
app.window().print_control_identifiers()
Control Identifiers:
Dialog - 'PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.py'    (L-9, T-9, R1929, B1039)
['Dialog', 'PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.pyDialog', 'PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.py']
child_window(title="PremiereVideoConstructor – startGUI.py", control_type="Window")
|
| Pane - 'Python Console'    (L49, T295, R1914, B899)
| ['Python ConsolePane', 'Python Console', 'Pane']
| child_window(title="Python Console", control_type="Pane")
|
| TitleBar - ''    (L0, T-6, R1920, B0)
| ['TitleBar']
|    |
|    | Menu - 'Система'    (L0, T0, R28, B28)
|    | ['Система', 'Menu', 'СистемаMenu', 'Система0', 'Система1']
|    | child_window(title="Система", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
|    |    |
|    |    | MenuItem - 'Система'    (L0, T0, R28, B28)
|    |    | ['Система2', 'MenuItem', 'СистемаMenuItem']
|    |    | child_window(title="Система", control_type="MenuItem")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Свернуть'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
|    | ['Button', 'Свернуть', 'СвернутьButton', 'Button0', 'Button1']
|    | child_window(title="Свернуть", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Восстановить'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
|    | ['Button2', 'Восстановить', 'ВосстановитьButton']
|    | child_window(title="Восстановить", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Закрыть'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
|    | ['Button3', 'ЗакрытьButton', 'Закрыть']
|    | child_window(title="Закрыть", control_type="Button")
Но сделать с ним ничего не могу: не могу получить доступ к его дочерним элементам. Это невозможно в принципе, или я что-то не так делаю? Пайчарм использовал для примера. Бэкенд uia.

Pane - это боль (pain). Обычно не автоматизируется в деталях. Но вообще консоль тоже через GUI никак и никогда не автоматизируется. Если нужно команду запустить и считать output, то надо использовать встроенный модуль subprocess и класс Popen (процесс), у которого можно читать stdout и stderr. Это единственно правильный путь для подобных случаев. Если нужно environment, специфический для PyCharm, то всегда можно руками сдампить его из консоли PyCharm и выставить отдельно в os.environ (ведёт себя как словарь) в скрипте, который уже запустит subprocess.Popen с этими переменными окружения (они наследуются дочерним процессом, хотя вроде это можно поменять).
